# Halt execution of calling procedure while timer runs a sub

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm using BPMCounter from Un4seen developments to get the beats per minute of a sound file and later update the ID3tag using taglib. The routine of getting the beats is in the timerBPM_Tick sub as below after "btnBPM" button is clicked

```
Private Sub btnBPM_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBPM.Click
    Bass.BASS_Init(2, 44100, BASSInit.BASS_DEVICE_DEFAULT, IntPtr.Zero)

    _fileName = "I:\TestMusic\Mitchell.mp3"
    'Private _stream As Integer
    '' create a BPMCounter instance, the timer will be fired every 20ms
    'Private _bpm As New BPMCounter(20, 44100)

    ' create a stream
    _stream = Bass.BASS_StreamCreateFile(_fileName, 0, 0, BASSFlag.BASS_DEFAULT)
    ' get the samplerate of that stream
    Dim info As New BASS_CHANNELINFO()
    Bass.BASS_ChannelGetInfo(_stream, info)
    ' and start playing the and also start the BPM counter
    If _stream <> 0 AndAlso Bass.BASS_ChannelPlay(_stream, False) Then
        'If _stream <> 0 AndAlso Bass.BASS_ChannelPlay(_stream, True) Then
        'playing...
        _bpm.Reset(info.freq)
        ' start our bpm timer callback
        TimerBPM.Start()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub timerBPM_Tick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TimerBPM.Tick
    If _stream = 0 OrElse Bass.BASS_ChannelIsActive(_stream) <> BASSActive.BASS_ACTIVE_PLAYING Then
        TimerBPM.Stop()
        Return
    End If
    beat = _bpm.ProcessAudio(_stream, True)      'true = beats only  false = anything like a beat
    If beat Then
        ' display the live calculated BPM value
        LabelBPM.Text = _bpm.BPM.ToString("#00.0")
    End If
End Sub
```

I've changed the procedure to now loop through a listbox getting the next selected audio file and starting the timerBPM to calculate the BPM. My dilemma is not with the 3rd party app but how to force the calling procedure to wait until the TimerBPM_Tick sub stops the timer otherwise the calling routine just continues to run through the loop.
Any assistance in pointing me to a solution much appreciated.

Comment: `the calling routine just continues to run through the loop` I don't see a loop. Do you have more code? I guess you didn't show the code which iterates the ListBox. That might be helpful. But I think your issue is in `TimerBPM.Start()` which does not block the caller. If so do you know how Timers work?

Comment: If I understand things correctly, it looks like you are trying to calculate BPM for an entire song at a time using an API that is designed for live updating of BPM as a song is playing.

Comment: @djv My minimal use of timers to date is usually to run for a set time then run another sub or delay execution of current code whereas here the timer keeps checking that the audio file is still active. The changed code just has a for each strAudio As String In lstFiles.SelectedItems after checking that there are selected items and set the _filename accordingly. The "Next" statement is before the End Sub line.

Comment: @adv12 Correct. The API calculates an average through the whole song. The intention is to update the ID3tag using taglib after each BPM has been found in each selected file

Comment: So am I correct that, intended use of the library aside, you really have no use for the live average feature and would be content with calculating a single number for each file all at once?

Comment: @adv12 If that was something I could do that would be awesome. Cut down on the time it'll take to do several selected files

Comment: Honestly it looks like you're just using the wrong tool for the job.  You might take a look at this: https://github.com/TheOsch/naudio-bpm.  But in any case, if you have to use this library, you could make your click handler async void and, after you start the BPM timer, do a little loop like ```while(TimerBPM.Enabled){await Task.Delay(10)}```

Comment: Does the entire song need to be played realtime in order to analyze it and set intervals then average it? Seems a little clunky

Comment: @djv yeah I looked into the library a bit.  It seems very playback/realtime focused.  I didn't see a non-playback-oriented API for BPM.

Comment: Handbrake can transcode an entire movie into another format in a couple minutes. There's no reason why an API which can perform Fourier analysis for beat frequency for example shouldn't exist. Seems like the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Morning @adv12, Being self taught, I've never come across the async void & await task.delay methods. I'm using vs 2019 & vb.net winforms. The suggested naudio-bpm appears to be web based & really to read files from a web server. The async void & await task.delay links that I've seen after a quick google all seem to be C# only? If it's available in VB.Net how would I implement it? My method of teaching myself is to read others codes on the web & understand what they're doing & of course what helpful people such as yourselves help me with when I get stuck

Comment: @HughSelfTaught naudio-bpm looks like a standard Console app to me.  I forgot you were using vb.net.  I googled, and there are Async and Await keywords there too.  You'll be better off just reading the docs than having me try to translate to a language I never use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/  And Task.Delay is part of .NET so it's available to both vb.net and C#.

Comment: Incidentally, given the relative popularity of C# and VB.NET and the fact that both give you access to the same underlying functionality, let me recommend that you switch languages.  You'll have a much easier time finding examples and getting coding help in C# than VB.

Comment: @adv12 Thanks for this. So far I've been successful converting C# code using http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/

Comment: @adv12 After reading the link you gave me, would I be correct in changing this click event Private Sub btnProcess_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProcess to Private Async Sub btnProcess_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnProcess.ClickAsync and then using async functions with await for the loop and also for the timerBPM so the one waits for the other? On a side note: I don't mind the whole song having to play as this is for dancing & BPM accuracy is important

Comment: No, the point is that the timer is enabled for the full time the song is playing, firing occasionally to do work.  You don’t want to interrupt any of that, so you set it going and then do a small inner loop that yields control back to the GUI thread until it detects that the timer is no longer enabled (i.e. the song is done).  When the timer is enabled again, you exit your inner loop (the while loop with the Task.Delay in it) and move on to the next song.

Comment: Your method signature looks approximately correct, though it will handle Click, not ClickAsync (which doesn’t exist)

Comment: @adv12 Hope you can still assist. Been sooo busy over this period. I have changed my btnProcess_Click procedure to the following:         If LView.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            For Each drv As ListViewItem In LView.SelectedItems
                strFile = txtFolder.Text & "\" & drv.Text

                Bass.BASS_Init(-1, 44100, BASSInit.BASS_DEVICE_DEFAULT, IntPtr.Zero)
                Await GetTimerBeatAsync()
            Next

            MessageBox.Show("Done")
            LView.Clear()
        End If          I then created this function to use the await:

Comment: @adv12 Sorry don't know how to add code here     Private Async Function GetTimerBeatAsync() As Task(Of Integer)
        _fileName = strFile
        txtProcessing.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFile)
        _stream = Bass.BASS_StreamCreateFile(_fileName, 0, 0, BASSFlag.BASS_DEFAULT)
        Dim info As New BASS_CHANNELINFO()
        Bass.BASS_ChannelGetInfo(_stream, info)
        If _stream <> 0 AndAlso Bass.BASS_ChannelPlay(_stream, True) Then
            _bpm.Reset(info.freq)
            TimerBPM.Start()
            Await ???
        End If     Don't know how to use the timer

Comment: @HughSelfTaught, sorry, comments aren't really a great format for this sort of help and I'm really more about pointing someone in the right direction than taking responsibility for someone else's problems.  Best of luck, and do consider learning C# and giving naudio another look.